# Varying the size of dots in a plot according to information contained in list

Tags: plotting, charts

Suppose I have the following coordinates that I want to plot:

```
xy = {{0.05, -0.000264728}, {0.15, -0.0125407}, {0.25, -0.0569049}, {0.35,-0.133636}, {0.45, -0.235416}, {0.55, -0.358514}, {0.65, -0.50575},{0.75, -0.68979}, {0.85, -0.948287}, {0.95, -1.46034}}
```

But suppose also, that I wish to vary the size of the dots in the plot using information contained in a corresponding list:

```
pointsize = {0.98, 0.94, 0.90, 0.83, 0.76, 0.66, 0.57, 0.41, 0.25, 0.09}
```

How can that be achieved? I suppose I need a base-size for points, and then weight this base by the content of the pointsize list, but exactly how that can be done in Mathematica I do not know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use several approaches:

**`BubbleChart`:**

```
bcdata = Join[xy, List /@ pointsize, 2];
BubbleChart[bcdata]
```

[image]

See the options [`BubbleScale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleScale.html) and [`BubbleSizes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleSizes.html) for various ways to associate the third column with bubble sizes.

**Graphics:**

Alternatively, you can use `Graphics` using some normalization of `pointsize` as the radii of disks centered on points in `xy`:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[1], Lighter@Blue, 
  Disk @@@ Transpose[{xy, Normalize[pointsize, Max]/20}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**ListPlot:**

```
ListPlot[List /@ xy, 
 PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[Lighter@Blue, 
    PointSize /@ (Normalize[pointsize, Max]/10)]], PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]